# How to automate EBS encryption with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am looking to encrypt my root EBS volumes for new EC2 environments that I create. I know that I can do this from the AWS console and from CloudFormation, but would like to be able to do so via an Elastic Beanstalk config file.

I have tried by setting the EBS volume in the launch configuration, however this only creates additional volumes from the root volume:

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
Properties:
  BlockDeviceMappings: [ DeviceName: "/dev/sdf1", Ebs: { Encrypted: true, VolumeSize: 8, VolumeType: gp2}]
```

I have also tried to create a new EBS volume on environment creation, however I am unsure how to dynamically get the EC2 instance's logical name (I used MyEC2 here for reference):

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
Properties:
  AutoEnableIO: true
  AvailabilityZone: { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyEC2", "AvailabilityZone" ] }
  Encrypted: true
  KmsKeyId: mykey
  Size: 8
  VolumeType: gp2
```

Essentially I need to be able to create a new environment with an encrypted root volume. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the availability zone the only place where you need the EC2 logical name?  Can you post your full launch configuration?

Comment: I believe the availability zone is the only place. Since this is Elastic Beanstalk, I don't have any other configuration aside from this snippet. I believe if I was using Cloud Formation it would be simple to get the name from

Comment: With the first approach, what is the outcome? Is it creating, but it's not encrypted?....or is the template not working?

Comment: The first approach will create a new volume, however the root volume is still attached which is unencrypted and in use

Comment: I don´t know if this is possible for EBS at least automatically using .ebextensions but sure it is for EFS which has been designed having scalability on mind. EFS filesystem can be created and mounted in multiple AZ/Subnets allowing traffic from the default AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance security group. https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-createfilesystem.config https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-php-wordpress/blob/master/.ebextensions/efs-create.config

Comment: @OscarNevarez from what I understand with EFS, an unencrypted root EBS will still be created for the Elastic Beanstalk environment

Answer (score 19):

As of May 23, 2019, you can **Opt-in to Default Encryption for New EBS Volumes**. Both EBS's (root/docker data) were encrypted on launch. This feature needs to be enabled per region.

**Test Setup**

Platform Version and Solution Stack Name: **Single Container Docker 18.06 version 2.12.11**

**AWS Console**

`EC2 Console > Settings > Always encrypt new EBS volumes`

**AWS CLI**

upgrade awscli first

```
pip install awscli --upgrade
```

enable

```
aws ec2 enable-ebs-encryption-by-default --region us-east-1
{
    "EbsEncryptionByDefault": true
}
```

disable

```
aws ec2 disable-ebs-encryption-by-default --region us-east-1
{
    "EbsEncryptionByDefault": false
}
```

get status

```
aws ec2 get-ebs-encryption-by-default --region us-east-1
{
    "EbsEncryptionByDefault": false
}
```

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-opt-in-to-default-encryption-for-new-ebs-volumes/

Comment: Have you confirmed this also works with Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @tavor999 yes, I confirmed this works with EB on Single Container Docker 18.06 version 2.12.11

Answer (score 10):

You cannot specify to encrypt a root volume using either CloudFormation or Beanstalk. The key is to use an AMI that has an encrypted root volume. This means copying the AMI that you want to use and encrypting it during the AMI copy process. Once you have an encrypted AMI, you would use that AMI Id in CloudFormation or Beanstalk to launch instances.

To encrypt a root volume:

- Select the AMI that you want to create your EC2 instance in the console.
- Copy the AMI selecting "encrypt" in the options. This will create a new AMI that has an encrypted root volume.
- Specify the new AMI when creating the instance.

This is the only method available on AWS to encrypt the root volume on an EC2 instance. Once you have an encrypted AMI, you can use this with any service where you can specify the AMI ImageId to create instances.

The encrypted volume will use KMS to manage the encryption keys. Note: there is a minor charge for each KMS key and usage charges.

You can also create an encrypted AMI using the CLI.

```
aws ec2 copy-image -r source_region -s source_ami_id \
  [-n ami_name] [-d ami_description] [-c token] \
  [--encrypted] [--kmsKeyID keyid]
```

Do not use AMIs created from snapshots when creating an encrypted AMI. AWS states that this can cause boot failures.

For Elastic Beanstalk here is a link to use a custom AMI:

[Using a Custom Amazon Machine Image (AMI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering what to do after enabling the default encryption setting, here is what I did:

I followed the advice above of turning the "Default Encryption for New EBS Volumes" setting on and then terminated my existing EC2 volume. Since Elastic Beanstalk includes [auto scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.as.html), auto-scaling automatically created another instance and this time, with an encrypted volume.