# How to use Beanstalk with default EBS encrpytion enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently enabled default ebs encryption as mentioned here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-opt-in-to-default-encryption-for-new-ebs-volumes/. Afterwards, when attempting to launch a beanstalk instance, I get a generic 'ClientError' and the instance immediately terminates. If I disabled default encryption it works fine.

Does anyone know what changes are required to get beanstalk to work with a customer managed encryption key? I suspected it was a permissions issue so I temporarily gave the beanstalk roles full admin access but that did not solve the issue. Is there something else I am missing?

I saw this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231052/how-to-automate-ebs-encryption-with-elastic-beanstalk) but it was before default EBS encryption was released and I was hoping to avoid having to copy and encrypt the AMI manually...

Comment: Are you using the default encryption key or a custom KMS key?

Comment: the custom KMS key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a custom CMK, you have to update the key policy and assign permissions explicitly. For EBS encryption, a principal usually requires the following permissions:

- kms:CreateGrant
- kms:Encrypt
- kms:Decrypt
- kms:ReEncrypt*
- kms:GenerateDataKey*
- kms:DescribeKey

The best way to troubleshoot key permission issues is to check the Cloudtrail event history. Filter the events  by event source and check if there is any "access denied" error.

> **Filter:** Event source: kms.amazonaws.com

You can see which action is denied here and adjust the key policy accordingly.  "User name" field in the event gives you a hint to determine the ARN of the principal to use in the policy.

In your case, it is very likely that one of the service-linked roles requires permissions to access the KMS key. There is a good explanation for key permissions [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=277523) for auto-scaling service-linked role.

Comment: THANK YOU.  Ultimately just needed to add the 'AutoScalingServiceRolePolicy' as a user on the EBS encryption key in the KMS GUI.  The tip about cloudtrail troubleshooting helped as well.